# Understanding resource and authority url

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, adal

I am trying to access azure resource manager through rest and part of the process is to provide an authorization header. I have been able to successfully retrieve the token by using adal library.

I can use either https://management.core.windows.net/ or  https://management.azure.com/ as the resource URL to get the token. What is the difference between two ?

I also would like to understand the difference between login.microsoftonline.com/ and https://login.windows.net/ as the authority URL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I can use either https://management.core.windows.net/ or
>   https://management.azure.com/ as the resource URL to get the token.
>   What is the difference between two ?

`management.core.windows.net` is the endpoint for `Azure Service Management REST API` while `management.azure.com` is the endpoint for `Azure Resource Manager REST API`.

> I also would like to understand the difference between
>   login.microsoftonline.com/ and https://login.windows.net/ as the
>   authority URL

Both of them are essentially the same but it is recommended that you use `login.microsoftonline.com` as `login.windows.net` redirects to that. So if you use former, you're saving on one redirect. However it is recommended that you start using former. Please read this blog post for more details: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2015/03/06/simplifying-our-azure-ad-authentication-flows/.